# How to provide two values in query string in LzBrowser.loadURL in openlaszlo

Tags: java, openlaszlo

How can i pass two values in a query string using LzBrowser.loadURL() in openlaszlo.

My sample code:

```
LzBrowser.loadURL("../modules/Index.jsp?base="+ canvas.base +" id=" + canvas.Id,"fraMain");
```

I am getting number Format exception:

java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1 base=1"]

Please help in solving this.

Thanks,

Raj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to provide & amp; instead of &. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You should add & between two query parameters . You should write like this

```
LzBrowser.loadURL("../modules/Index.jsp?base="+ canvas.base +"&id=" + canvas.Id,"fraMain");
```

Answer (score 1):

The number format exception means, that at some point in your code the browser tries to parse a string into a number. Which version of OpenLaszlo did you use, and which runtime?

Based on the use of LzBrowser (starting with OpenLaszlo 4.1 you have to use lz.Browser instead) it seems that you are using either a 3.x or the 4.0 release of OpenLaszlo.

If you want to use the ampersand "&" within methods containing JavaScript code, the XML entity rules apply (everything which starts with an & will be treated as an XML entitity). Adding  sections in your methods will let you use the & as you'd do in normal JavaScript or ActionScript code, e.g.

```
<canvas debug="true">

  <button text="Open URL" onclick="canvas.loadUrl()" />

  <attribute name="base" type="number" value="99" />

  <attribute name="iD" type="number" value="10" />

  <method name="loadUrl"><![CDATA[
    lz.Browser.loadURL("http://www.google.com?base=" + canvas.base + "&iD=" + canvas.iD, "_blank");
  ]]></method>

</canvas>
```

Without the CDATA section, the following compiler error will be thrown:

> loadurl.lzx:10:71: The reference to entity "iD" must end with the ';'
>   delimiter. Look for a misplaced or unescaped ampersand ('&') character
>   in your source code.

The described workaround of using "&" instead of "&" and no CDATA section is of course a valid option - although it reduced the readability of the JavaScript code in my eyes.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are two ways to do this, both of the following are correct:

1) Escape the special HTML characters (in this case &) by surrounding the internal code with <![CDATA[ and ]]> tags:

```
<method name="loadUrl">
<![CDATA[
    lz.Browser.loadURL("http://www.google.com?base=" + canvas.base + "&iD=" + canvas.iD, "_blank");
]]>
</method>
```

2) HTML-entity encode the & character to &amp;

```
<method name="loadUrl">
    lz.Browser.loadURL("http://www.google.com?base=" + canvas.base + "&amp;iD=" + canvas.iD, "_blank");
</method>
```

Which method you choose is up to your own preference.